# different viewport meta tag for landscape devices

Tags: ipad, landscape, viewport, metatag

is it possible to use a different meta tag for landscape device vs. portrait device

e.g. I want to use this meta tag for ipad portrait mode only

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.70, maximum-scale=1">
```

and for landscape mode on the ipad i want to change the initial-scale to this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```